# Pull from same row as MAX in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get a list of users that has sent me a message, as well as the timestamp and subject of that message.

`SELECT user_id,subject,MAX(timestamp) FROM messages GROUP BY user_id`

How can I make the `subject` pull from the same row that has the `MAX(timestamp)`? Is it possible without a subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a direct comparison in the `where` clause, here with a correlated subquery:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.timestamp = (select max(m2.timestamp)
                     from messages m2
                     where m2.user_id = m.user_id
                    );
```